# Conditional data validation using excel lists

Tags: excel, validation

I am building a workbook to manage the expenses of a home renovation business. The table named 'Jobs' contains a 'status' column, which can contain various options such as 'Job started', 'Job complete', 'invoice sent' etc.

I intend to have another table called 'expenses', where I can add expenses, but only to jobs that have status set to 'Job started'. To do this, I would have a column with List Data Validation, but I don't know how to generate the list of jobs that only have the appropriate corresponding status.

Expenses table:

[image: expenses table]

Jobs table:

[image: Jobs table]

Misc lists:

[image: misc lists]

Edit for clarity:
In the sample shown, when I click on items in the Job Site column of the 'Expenses' table, I would like to see 'Werribee', 'Croydon South' and Pascoe Vale South' in the list (since their status is 'Job started')

Comment: Which column from the Jobs table do you want to add. you could use a simple formulae like `=SUMIF(I2:I12,"Job started",F2:F12)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula.

in Expense table you A2 put this.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Jobs!$A$2:$A$999,SMALL(IF(Jobs!$I$2:$I$999="Job started",ROW($1:$100)),ROW()-1)),"")
```

basically this looks up to worksheet Job, A2:A999 and checks if its status is "Job started", If its validation is positive, it copies the value from the range A2:A999 which has the "Job started", paste this on each cells on Expense table.

Don't forget this is a array formula so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after copying the formula.

Answer (score 0):

In an empty column (say F) beside the expenses table use the below 2 formula

for first row

```
F2 = 1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((JOBS!$I$2:$I$14="Job started")*(ROW(JOBS!$I$2:$I$14)>1)*ROW(JOBS!$I$2:$I$14)),1)
```

and next row onward

```
F3 = 1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((JOBS!$I$2:$I$14="Job started")*(ROW(JOBS!$I$2:$I$14)>F2)*ROW(JOBS!$I$2:$I$14)),1)
```

Drag down F3. Notice the `>1` in `F2` and `>F2` in `F3` and onward. This will give all row numbers that have "Job started" as status in the Jobs table

Once you have the row numbers, you can use `Index(Jobs table, row num, column num)` to get other data for those rows

Make sure the Jobs table range that you input in the formula starts form the first row i.e. A1:J7 as shown in your image

Example
[image: Example]